# Is it possible to remove or disable the transparency overlay from the Restarting, Ctrl-Alt-Del and Sign-in screens?

Tags: windows-10, colors

My accent color in Personalize > Colors is `10, 39, 116`.

On the Restarting, Ctrl-Alt-Delete and Sign-in screens there is exactly a 20% transparency color overlay (black). I calculated this exactly by recreating it in Photoshop.

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to remove or disable this transparent overlay -- or it could possibly be some other kind of color darkening trick, not exactly sure.

[image: My accent color versus the colors compared to the Ctrl-Alt-Del and Restarting screen colors]

Answer (score 0):

To turn transparency effects on or off :

In *Settings > Personalization > Colors*, toggle "Transparency effects".

Comment: The answer, if there is one, will not be found in any MS control panel, settings app, or group policy. It *may* be found buried deep in the registry, however.

Comment: You mean it doesn't work ? The matching registry entry is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize`, item `EnableTransparency`, value `0` is Off. But I don't believe that it will work better. Did you try to log off and on again?

Comment: Right, that setting and matching registry entry does disable the *Acrylic effect* and blurring from the sign-in screen, but it doesn't affect the 20% darken overlay.

Comment: I haven't found any registry item that controls that, and I searched.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Yeah, I think this is a lost cause.